# auto suggest using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to implement auto suggest for text box.I have checked other posts nothing seems to be working for me.I tried both in web application and website.Please figure outthe mistake in in my code.when i type letter in textbox nothing happens.i could see webservice results in browser.

delete.aspx

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Delete.aspx.cs"
   Inherits="WebApplication2.Delete" %>
  <%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
  Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
 TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>

<body>  
  <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div> 
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" 
      EnablePartialRendering="true" 
      runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>  
           <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Width="400px" ></asp:TextBox> 
           <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender  runat="server"    ID="autoComplete1" 
             TargetControlID="myTextBox"
             ServiceMethod="Information"
             ServicePath="~/WebService1.asmx"
             OnClientItemOut="Information"
             MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
             CompletionInterval="1000"
             EnableCaching="true"
             CompletionSetCount="5"   
             ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
               </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender> 
        </div>  
         </form>
         </body>
```

webservice1.asmx

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Services;

   namespace WebApplication2
   {

   [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]



public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public string[]Information(string prefixText)
    {


        RDFEntities db = new RDFEntities();
        var allrows = from s1 in db.RDFMatch_v where s1.RIC.StartsWith(prefixText) select s1.RIC;



        return allrows.ToArray();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: i am curious to know why you haven't considered jquery autocomplete.

Comment: can you please provide me the link.I'll try.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the asp.net ScriptManager, try to use the ToolkitScriptManager like so:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: i tried this with @Wouter de Kort changes .it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `OnClientItemOut="Information"` from your ASPX. You have no Information handler defined in your JavaScript.

And then add the `[ScriptService]` attribute to your Web Service.

A handy tool for inspecting what's going on is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It will show you the request going to your server and the response.

Comment: On what are you getting the 400? On the page itself?

Comment: no. the response in the fiddler.I tried jquery with genric handler.It is working fine.Thanks.